# Provide default django login view under a url argument

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

What I want to lay out is a design that works similar to the following. I have a `urls.py` definition like:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/login/$', auth_views.login, name='customer_login'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'customer_login'}),
```

where the slug identifies some client and I want to provide a login view for each client.

What I am basically struggling with at the moment is the fact that the default django login view can't handle the additional kwarg `slug`. And I also want all the redirect_to links from the login & logout view to be based on that `slug` value.

My question:

- Is there some solution for this problem?
- Is the above layout a bad design and should it be handled differently?

Comment: I'm confused before the user login how are you able to use `slug` to provide different login? Are you saying you want different group of people to use different endpoints to login?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the login view to do with this argument. I suspect your problem is deeper than just the URL.

Comment: as @DanielRoseman said this seems a deeper design problem.